# Creating GGPLOT Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function, 'n' rolls of 'k' dice, in which the result is the sum of 'k' rolls.

```
rolldie = function(n, k){
  # Your code here
  die=sample(1:6, size = k, replace = TRUE)
  replicate(n, sum(sample(c(1:6),k, replace=TRUE)))
}
rolldie(5, 4)
```

I then have to create a ggplot histogram to show the results of the function, using n=1000 with whatever values of k. That is where I am stuck, I am not sure how to create this histogram for the results of rolldie.

Comment: ggplot has pretty good documentation and links to several in-depth tutorials. After reading through some of those, where *exactly* do you get stuck? Have you tried `geom_histogram`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot expects a data frame, so you could try this ...

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(die_sums = rolldie(1000, 10))|>
  ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(aes(die_sums), binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a simplified `rolldie` function.
Roll the dies, table the results, coerce the table to `data.frame` and plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

rolldie <- function(n, k){
  replicate(n, sum(sample(6, k, replace=TRUE)))
}

set.seed(2022)
n <- 1000
Points <- rolldie(n, 4)

Points <- as.data.frame(table(Points))
ggplot(Points, aes(Points, Freq)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
library(janitor)
data <- tabyl(rolldie(1000, 1)) %>% rename(Number = 1)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x= as.factor(Number), y=n, label = Number))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = -0.5)
```